# Inherit but dont display

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way that i could have an element pass on a style but not to use it itself?

Example:

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.one {
  background: url(image);
}
.two {
  background: inherit;
 !!! I want it to be passed down but not displayed here
}
.three {
  background: inherit;
}
```

Comment: seems a bit weird you would want this. What is the effect you are after?

Comment: There is no such `background: bypass;` in CSS

Comment: Please don't ask [XY questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Better to just use an additional class on one and three.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but not this way. You can introduce a variable:

CSS:

```
:root {
  --onebg: url(image);
}

.one {
  background: var(--onebg);
}

.two {
  background: <someOtherValue>;
}

.three {
  background: var(--onebg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you can make `three` inherit `one`'s background and you can change the background of both by altering the variable's value.

Comment: This wouldnt be inheriting though would it? Its the same as just setting the background again in .three right?

Comment: Yes, but this way you can change the background of both by just setting a value for `onebg`. It is almost the same as inheritance: you set a background on `one` and that same background is used in `three`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the size to be `0`

```css
.one {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300);
}

.two {
  background: inherit;
  background-size: 0 0;
}

.three {
  background: inherit;
  background-size: initial;/* update the size here like you want */
}

div {
  padding: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for some cases, but it doesn't directly answer the question. The background example may not be inclusive of the actual use case.

Comment: @isherwood The background example may not be inclusive of the actual use case --> we have no information about the background use so this is answering the question as stated since the second element is showing nothing like expected